# Is it OK to pass on OAuth Access Token between services?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization, access-token, microservices

Considering the following scenario in a context of the SSO/OAuth/microservices:

1. User successfully logs-in to the web application using OAuth's Implicit Flow.
2. Web app requests some data from **Service A** and **Service B** passing on user's Access Token to authorize both requests.
3. **Service A** also calls **Service B** (passing on the same Access Token!) in order to build response to the initial Web App request.

Now, is this OK to pass on the user's Access Token from **Service A** to **Service B**?

Or should **Service A** use "Client Credentials" grant to obtain its own Access Token to authorize call to the **Service B**?

**UPDATE**:
Please assume both services are owned by the same organization and both trust the same Authorization Server. Also both services are behind the same API Gateway which validates Access Tokens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on who is controlling the web application, Service A and Service B. If they're all run by the same party there's no problem in passing the token on since it stays within the same security domain.

But if e.g. Service B is run by a 3rd party then things become problematic as the administrator of Service B can pickup the access token and call Service A as if it were your web application, potentially getting access to resources that it should not have access to.

You'll also note that if Service A and Service B are owned by 2 different parties, other than you, your web application should also obtain two different access tokens respectively for calling Service A and Service B to prevent the same security issue.

So the answer really is: it depends on who is controlling what i.e. if the token is crossing an administrative/security domain.

Comment: So you're saying it is OK as long as Web App and both Services are controlled/owned by the same organization? Are you aware of any document (RFC, OAuth guideline, etc.) which would cover such a case? The reason I ask is that I agree with your answer and I am looking for extra "ammo" to discuss this with SSO team within my company.

Comment: it is more like a generic security consideration: access tokens should not be leaked outside of Client/RS/AS, see: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6819#section-4.6.1

Comment: Actually in case of the OAuth Implict Flow Access Tokens have to go out of the RS/AS boundary. In case of Authorization Code flow or Client Credentials flow indeed tokens should not leak outside RS/AS boundary.

Comment: tokens always go to the Client, in any grant type so they always leave the RS/AS; the point is that they don't leak to a different Client/RS than the one intended for

Comment: Good point. I actually had User Agent in mind when I said that in case of Authorization Code flow token does not leave Client/RS/AS boundary.

Answer (score 2):

The way I see this is, if you have 2 different services trusting the same IDP(STS) then you can have service A requesting a token and then you can pass the same token to service B and let service B validate the token again. It is ok to pass the token as you dont want user to log in again for another service call.

Also, it depends on the way you have services setup. If service A needs some data from service B to provide data back to the user then we should pass the same user token. I dont think that services should have their access token.

Using user token really helps in identifying claims and data access at each service levels. So it is always better to pass the user token and let each service validate the token before sending the data out to the user.

Comment: Actually OAuth 2.0 defines "Client Credentials" grant type so generally speaking service A calling other service B may use this grant type to obtain its own Access Token. My question is about a specific case when Service A already has user's Access Token which technically may be reused by Service A to call Service B. The question is if this is a right thing to do.

Comment: Yes it is ok to pass in the service token to other service as you dont want any service to to be open to public facing. Say response from Service A requires some data from Service B then user does not need to know that. Also in a scenario where Service B can be called independently as well as from Service A, no matter who calls the service to get the data token must be provided. In case of call from A it will pass in the token which it has already and when user calls it, he will pass the token.

Answer (score 0):

I have found below 3 options:

- If each microservice is verifying the token then we can pass the same token. But the problem is - in between same token can be expired.
- If we use client_credentials grant then there we are having two issues: one is, we need to send the username/id in next microservice. Another one is, we need to request two times - first for getting the access token, next for actual call.
- If we do the token verification in API gateway only (not in microservices) then from the API gateway we need to send the username in every microservices. And microservices implementation needs to be changed to accept that param/header.